# How do I distinguish pressing a button from releasing a button, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**This is what I tried:**

```
function move(e)
{
   if (e.keyCode==32)
   {
     up=0;
     bottonup=650;
     var temp="rect("+up+"px,auto,"+bottomup+"px,auto)";
     rect2.style.clip=temp;
   }
}
function move2(d){
  if (d.keyCode==32)
  {
    up=0;
    bottonup=0;
    var temp="rect("+up+"px,auto,"+bottomup+"px,auto)";
    rect2.style.clip=temp;
  }
}
document.onkeydown=move;
document.onkeyup=move2;
```

My problem is when I press a button or release a button, the transition starts again and because of that, the animation slips.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this means `My problem is when I press a button or release a button, the transition starts again and because of that, the animation slips.`

Comment: Can you please add an example snippet which we can execute and see? You can use the snippet button in the question editor to add it.

Comment: When I press or release the 32 key, the condition is always true. Therefore, the transition always restarts. How could I distinguish it by starting the animation on it separately when pressed and released. @Link

Answer (score 1):

Every **Events** has a **type**. Check against it.

```js
const EventType = {
  keyup: "keyup",
  keydown: "keydown"
}

const move = (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    if (event.type === EventType.keydown) {
      console.log(`${event.code} is pressed.`)
    } else if (event.type === EventType.keyup) {
      console.log(`${event.code} is released.`)
    }
  }
}


document.body.onkeydown = move
document.body.onkeyup = move
```

Press **Enter** to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

When working with animation you usually need some kind of condition logic. For ex: waiting for the animation to finish before triggering it again.

```
let pressed = false

function down () {
    // isAnimationDone -> holding key will not re-trigger animation if it's not finish
    // pressed -> wait for the key to be release before being able to call the animation again
    if (!pressed && isAnimationDone) {
      // do animation
      pressed = true
    }
}

function up () {
  pressed = false
}
```